# VB.NET progressbar based on cmd output

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I am bluilding an application these days on vb.net using VS2017. One of the app's features is a button that users will click, choose installation folder and the files for a game server will start downloading.

The app downloads the game server files via SteamCMD. It's like windows cmd. SteamCMD runs on the background when it's started. The app has a textbox in which users will be able to see SteamCMD's output.

I have added a progressbar in the app. In order i animate it, i have to get some specific numbers from each line of SteamCMD's output.

With the following function i start SteamCMD:

```
Private Sub StartSteamCMD()
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C steamcmd +runscript " + temp + "my_app\install_update.txt")
        With psi
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardError = True
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
            .StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
        End With
        process = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
        AddHandler process.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
        AddHandler process.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
        AddHandler process.Exited, AddressOf Process_Exited
        process.Start()
        process.BeginOutputReadLine()
        process.BeginErrorReadLine()
        process.Close()
    End Sub
```

And with the two following functions i transfer SteamCMD's output to the textbox:

```
Private Sub Async_Data_Received(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Invoke(New InvokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_Output), e.Data)
End Sub

Private Sub Sync_Output(text As String)
    TextBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine)
    TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

While SteamCMD is downloading the files, the output looks like this:

```
Update state (0x61) downloading, progress: 0.07 (12054911 / 16483164234)
```

The two numbers the progressbar needs are the last two. The very last one is the total file size that will be downloaded. While 12054911 is the file size that has been downloaded already and changes on every new line.

With the following code the app is supposed to get those two numbers from every new line and animate the progressbar:

```
Try
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) And (e.Data.Contains("downloading")) Then
        Dim initialLine As String() = e.Data.Split(New String() {"(", " / ", ")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If initialLine.Contains(" / ") Then
            Dim targetSize As String = initialLine(4)
            Dim targetSizeInt As Integer = 0
            Integer.TryParse(targetSize, targetSizeInt)
            Dim currentSize As String = initialLine(3)
            Dim currentSizeInt As Integer = 0
            Integer.TryParse(currentSize, currentSizeInt)
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = targetSizeInt
            ProgressBar1.Value = currentSizeInt
        End If
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

**.:UPDATED:.**

I placed the above code in the "Async_Data_Received" function under the "Invoke" function. "Debug.Print(ex.ToString())" didn't return anything. I replaced it with "MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)" and i got the following (translated from greek to english):

> The value '252043' is not a valid value for 'Value'. 'Value' must be
>   between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
>   Parameter's name: Value

I commented the "ProgressBar1.Value = currentSizeInt" line and added "MsgBox(ProgressBar1.Maximum)" under the "ProgressBar1.Maximum = targetSizeInt" line. For some reason MsgBox was keep giving me "0" over and over.

I changed the "Dim targetSizeInt As Integer = 0" and "Integer.TryParse(targetSize, targetSizeInt)" lines to "Dim targetSizeInt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(targetSize)". I got the following as exception:

> The value was either too big or too small for an Int32.

In that case a good move would be to changed the "Dim targetSizeInt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(targetSize)" line to "Dim targetSizeInt As Long = Convert.ToInt64(targetSize)". But that wouldn't solve the issue because the "Maximum" property of the progressbar is Int32.

As a result, i added "targetSize = targetSize.Substring(0, 10)" under "Dim targetSize As String = initialLine(4)". As for currentSize, first i had to get its length. Then check if its length is >1 and if it is, do "currentSize = currentSize.Substring(0, currentLength - 1)".

In this way the amount of characters currentSize and targetSize will have, will always be in integer's value range. I also switched back to the Integer.TryParse method since i believe it's better, safer and more reliable.

**I added all this information in order i help others who may have similar issue. With all this information i believe they will understand each step i took till i end up to the final working code, which is the following:**

```
Try
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) And (text.Contains("downloading")) Then
        Dim initialLine As String() = text.Split(New String() {"(", " / ", ")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim targetSize As String = initialLine(4)
        targetSize = targetSize.Substring(0, 10)
        Dim targetSizeInt As Integer = 0
        Integer.TryParse(targetSize, targetSizeInt)
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = targetSizeInt
        Dim currentSize As String = initialLine(3)
        Dim currentLength As Integer = currentSize.Length
        If currentLength > 1 Then
            currentSize = currentSize.Substring(0, currentLength - 1)
            Dim currentSizeInt As Integer = 0
            Integer.TryParse(currentSize, currentSizeInt)
            ProgressBar1.Value = currentSizeInt
        End If
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Surround that entire block with a Try/Catch and debug print the exception when it's thrown

Comment: A crash is an unhandled exception. The first step is ALWAYS to handle the exception and get all the information you can from it.

Comment: Btw, you can split e.data like this: `Dim result() As String = e.data.Split(New String() {"(", " / ", ")"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. Your Current and Total values will be strings number 3 and 4 (If the string you're splitting is the one that starts with "Update state", but it's not clear when you are identifying it).

Comment: @Jimi          Thanks for the tip, i made my code a bit shorter with that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney   Thanks for the advice, i will try to keep that in mind.

Comment: @ChaseRocker   Thanks for the suggestion. Thanks to that i started working on the issue and finally solve it.

Comment: Guys i updated the original post and added every step i did in order to solve the issue and end up to the final working code. In case you want to take a look, hit ctrl + f, search for UPDATED and start reading from there.